# How to remove last/first character(s) if they are not alphabetic/number?

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I want my string to only contain dash/alphabetic letter/number. I have converted all special characters to dash using

```
string %>% 
  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "-", .) %>%
  gsub(" ", "-", .) %>%
  gsub("\\-+", "-", .)
```

How to validate/remove last/first character(s) if they are not alphabetic/number in a string using regex?

Example input:

```
"-example-one111-"  "-222example-two" "333example-333three333-"
```

Expected output:

```
"example-one111"  "222example-two" "333example-333three333"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
trimws(gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "-", string), whitespace="-")
```

The `gsub` part replaces sequences of consecutive punctuation or whitespace chars with a single `-` char.

The `trimws` removes hyphens on both ends of each string item.

R test:

```r
> string <- c("-example-one111-", "---222example-two", "333example-333three333----")
> trimws(gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "-", string), whitespace="-")
[1] "example-one111"         "222example-two"         "333example-333three333"
```

Another way to write this is

```r
trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+", "-", string), whitespace="-")
```

where `[^[:alnum:]]+` matches one or more alphanumeric chars.

Comment: I think `[^[:alnum:]]` would fit better than `[[:punct:][:space:]]`, given OP’s stated requirement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I just merged the current regexps in the question into a single `gsub`. However, `[^[:alnum:]]+` might be a better bet especially if the string can contain some unprintable chars.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can use

```
> gsub(".*?([[:alnum:]].*[[:alnum:]]).*", "\\1", string)
[1] "example-one111"         "222example-two"         "333example-333three333"

> gsub("^[^[:alnum:]]+|[^[:alnum:]]+$", "", string)
[1] "example-one111"         "222example-two"         "333example-333three333"
```